# How to use branch() method to get a downstream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

in kafka-streams the branch()-method on a stream is deprecated.
I found some code snippets from COnfluent that I should use now the split() and branch() method like this:

```
artikelEvents.split()
                .branch((key, val) -> val.getKategorie().equals("Computer & Büro"), Branched.as("computer"))
                .branch((key, val) -> val.getKategorie().equals("Smartphones"), Branched.as("smartphones"))
                .branch((key, val) -> val.getKategorie().equals("Fotografie"), Branched.as("fotografie"))
        ;
```

My question is how can I get the results of the branching in separate downstreams?

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some research I found a solution that works for me:

```
final Map<String, KStream<String, ArtikelEvent>> branchedArtikelEventMap = artikelEvents.split(Named.as("branch-"))
                .branch((key, val) -> val.getKategorie().equals("Computer & Büro"), Branched.as("computer"))
                .branch((key, val) -> val.getKategorie().equals("Smartphones"), Branched.as("smartphones"))
                .branch((key, val) -> val.getKategorie().equals("Fotografie"), Branched.as("fotografie"))
                .defaultBranch();
```